# How to link validation layers?

Tags: android, vulkan

I'm have some trouble with the creation of the renderpass so I want to enable some validation layers. But when I add them to the CMakeLists.txt file, and then try to run the project I get this error Message. Is there a way to load the libVkLayer_..._validation.so files?

```
FAILED: cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\Lacko\AppData\Local\Android\sdk11\ndk-bundle\toolchains\llvm\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\clang++.exe  --target=aarch64-none-linux-android --gcc-toolchain=C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64 --sysroot=C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/sysroot -fPIC -isystem C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/sysroot/usr/include/aarch64-linux-android -D__ANDROID_API__=26 -g -DANDROID -ffunction-sections -funwind-tables -fstack-protector-strong -no-canonical-prefixes -Wa,--noexecstack -Wformat -Werror=format-security -std=c++11 -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions -O0 -fno-limit-debug-info  -Wl,--exclude-libs,libgcc.a -Wl,--exclude-libs,libatomic.a -nostdlib++ --sysroot C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/platforms/android-26/arch-arm64 -Wl,--build-id -Wl,--warn-shared-textrel -Wl,--fatal-warnings -LC:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a -Wl,--no-undefined -Wl,-z,noexecstack -Qunused-arguments -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -shared -Wl,-soname,libvulkan_module.so -o ..\..\..\..\build\intermediates\cmake\debug\obj\arm64-v8a\libvulkan_module.so CMakeFiles/vulkan_module.dir/src/main/cpp/vulkan_func.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vulkan_module.dir/src/main/cpp/vulkan_base.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vulkan_module.dir/src/main/cpp/vulkan_render_surface.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vulkan_module.dir/src/main/cpp/vulkan_draw_command.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vulkan_module.dir/src/main/cpp/vulkan_render_command.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vulkan_module.dir/src/main/cpp/vulkan_commands.cpp.o CMakeFiles/vulkan_module.dir/src/main/cpp/vulkan_module.cpp.o -LC:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/vulkan/src/build-android/jniLibs/mips -lVkLayer_core_validation -lVkLayer_threading -lVkLayer_parameter_validation -lVkLayer_object_tracker -lVkLayer_unique_objects -llog -latomic -lm "C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a/libc++_static.a" "C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libs/arm64-v8a/libc++abi.a" && cd ."
C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: skipping incompatible C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/vulkan/src/build-android/jniLibs/mips/libVkLayer_core_validation.so when searching for -lVkLayer_core_validation
C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lVkLayer_core_validation
C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: skipping incompatible C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/vulkan/src/build-android/jniLibs/mips/libVkLayer_threading.so when searching for -lVkLayer_threading
C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lVkLayer_threading
C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: skipping incompatible C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/vulkan/src/build-android/jniLibs/mips/libVkLayer_parameter_validation.so when searching for -lVkLayer_parameter_validation
C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lVkLayer_parameter_validation
C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: skipping incompatible C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/vulkan/src/build-android/jniLibs/mips/libVkLayer_object_tracker.so when searching for -lVkLayer_object_tracker
C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lVkLayer_object_tracker
C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: skipping incompatible C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/sources/third_party/vulkan/src/build-android/jniLibs/mips/libVkLayer_unique_objects.so when searching for -lVkLayer_unique_objects
C:/Users/Lacko/AppData/Local/Android/sdk11/ndk-bundle/toolchains/aarch64-linux-android-4.9/prebuilt/windows-x86_64/lib/gcc/aarch64-linux-android/4.9.x/../../../../aarch64-linux-android/bin\ld: cannot find -lVkLayer_unique_objects
clang++.exe: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

This is the CMakeList.txt file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

link_directories(${ANDROID_NDK}/sources/third_party/vulkan/src/build-android/jniLibs/mips)

add_library( native-lib
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp
             src/main/cpp/graphics_module.cpp)

add_library( vulkan_module
             SHARED
             src/main/cpp/vulkan_func.cpp
             src/main/cpp/vulkan_base.cpp
             src/main/cpp/vulkan_render_surface.cpp
             src/main/cpp/vulkan_draw_command.cpp
             src/main/cpp/vulkan_render_command.cpp
             src/main/cpp/vulkan_commands.cpp
             src/main/cpp/vulkan_module.cpp)


find_library( log-lib
              log )

target_link_libraries(vulkan_module
                      VkLayer_core_validation
                      VkLayer_threading
                      VkLayer_parameter_validation
                      VkLayer_object_tracker
                      VkLayer_unique_objects
                      ${log-lib} )

target_link_libraries( native-lib
                       vulkan_module
                       android
                       ${log-lib} )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't link the validation layers. All you need to do is to include the validation layer binaries in your apk along with your apk or somewhere in a system wide path, and then it's just enabling the layers to make validation work. Locating and loading the libraries is then done by the loader.

If you're using NDK r12 (or later) pre-built validation layers are included and can be easily added via gradle. See the official documentation for this [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/graphics/validation-layer).

The other option is to manually build the Android validation layers for your target architecture from the [official repository](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers) and add those manually to your Android build. While this requires more effort you always get the latest validation functionality.

Comment: How can I access my ndk location in my gradle files?

Comment: android.ndkDirectory =>
main.jniLibs.srcDir "$android.ndkDirectory/sources/third_party/vulkan/src/build-android/jniLibs"